# Plausible starting parameters for a Moon suicide burn

Tags: rockets, landing, lunar-landing

I just created a [Modelica Model](http://pastebin.com/qwXLu3Ta) of a rocket landing in vacuum. Now I attempt to verify it against reality. However, I have a hard time to figure out some plausible initial parameters. Apollo 11's Eagle had a Periapsis of 15km. But what was its initial speed?

I assume that everyone does one deorbit burn and later attempts to get as close to a suicide burn as reasonable. So I modeled my experiment after a falling mass under retrograde thrust in a cartesian coordinate system. Obviosuly, this model has a hard time when it comes to very long landing approaches (since the cartesian coordinates to not take into account the curvature of the target body), so lowering the periapsis to 0 is not an option right now (although probably the most efficient approach). I arbitrarily choose an initial surface velocity of 1km/s which gave me a landing at 140km.

So what is a plausible surface speed after the deorbit burn?

Comment: Start from the end: Model a launch from the Lunar surface, to the orbit. Of course you'll have to tweak fuel usage to be negative ;) Once you achieve the orbit, you have your "initial" parameters, just replay the whole thing backwards.

Answer (score 6):

[This document](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_11g_Lunar_Orbit_Phase.htm) provides the Apollo 11 LM velocity at the start of powered descent as 5564.9 ft/s.